# abnormal loading after booting from an emergency mode in linux parrotOS

Tags: linux, system, boot, system-error, parrot-os

so after around 1 year, i finally got to change keyboard for the unused laptop, the laptop OS is parrot, when starting, the system show the 'emergency mode' =

Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type “journalctl -xb” to view system logs, “systemctl reboot” to reboot, “systemctl default” or ^D to try again to boot into default mode.

Give root password for maintenance (or type control-D to continue):

this issue is solved, next actions i take following from this source : https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K97520510

so after rebooting, it stuck on parrot logo now for 1 hour, looks like a loading, because outside the logo there is a border thats keeps going around

whats the matter now? does anyone know why? or can give me some article to read regarding this issue

thanks

i dunno whats wrong, so i'm still searching whats the issue after rebooting from the emergeny mode